# Draw points with different point size

Tags: webgl

I have to draw something and I need to use two or more size points. I don't know how to get it, I only have one point size from my vertex shader.

```
<script id="myVertexShader" 
          type="x-shader/x-vertex">#version 300 es

      in  vec3 VertexPosition;
      in  vec4 VertexColor;

      out vec4 colorOut;

      uniform float pointSize;

      void main()  {

        colorOut    = VertexColor;
        gl_Position = vec4(VertexPosition, 1.0);
        gl_PointSize = 10.0;

      }

    </script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Answer: You set `gl_PointSize`

Examples:

Using a constant

```
 gl_PointSize = 20.0;
```

Using a uniform

```
 uniform float pointSize;
 gl_PointSize = pointSize;
```

Using some arbitrary formula

```
 // base the size on the red and blue colors
 gl_PointSize = abs(VertexColor.r * VertexColor.b) * 20.0;
```

Using a an attribute

```
 attrbute float VertexSize;
  ...
 gl_PointSize = VertexSize;
```

Any combination of the above (eg:

```
 attrbute float VertexSize;
 uniform float baseSize;

 // use a uniform, an atribute, some random formula, and a constant
 gl_PointSize = baseSize + VertexSize + abs(VertexColor.r * VertexColor.b) * 10.0;
```

PS: the forumla above is nonsense. The point is you set `gl_PointSize`. How you set it is up to you.

Note there are issues with `gl.POINTS`

1. WebGL implementations have a maximum point size. That maximum size is not required > 1.0. So if you want to draw points of any size you can not use `gl.POINTS`
2. WebGL doesn't guarantee whether or not large points who's center is outside the viewport will be drawn. So if you want to draw sizes larger than 1.0 and you want them to behave the same across devices you can't use `gl.POINTS`

See [this](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-drawing-without-data.html#pointsissues)